# Error in sklearn Gridsearch CV python NOTSET

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, gridsearchcv

I am trying to run following code for regression analysis using RF and GridSearchCV

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
param_grid = {
    'bootstrap': [True],
    'max_depth': [80, 90, 100, 110],
    'max_features': [2,3],
    'min_samples_leaf': [3, 4, 5],
    'min_samples_split': [8, 10, 12],
    'n_estimators': [5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50],
    'criterion' :['gini', 'entropy']
}
rf = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=1234)
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = rf, param_grid = param_grid,cv = 3, n_jobs = -1, verbose = 2)
```

When I am running following code:

```
grid_search.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

I am getting following error:

```
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/_pytest/compat.py", line 39
        NOTSET: "Final" = NotSetType.token  # noqa: E305
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?
I had used RF regression with no of trees=10 earlier and got results, but when I am trying CV it throws this error. Any suggestions?

Comment: which python version are you using ? 3.5 ?

Comment: I am using Python 3.5.2 on azure databricks

Comment: Please provide the full error traceback.  I'm not sure why pytest would be getting involved here.  But see https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/7808#issuecomment-744161357.

Comment: that is the total error message I am getting. Will try to get traceback. thanks for the link